# Symfony2: web debug toolbar throws FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function getUser() on a non-object after registering twig-extension

Tags: php, symfony

please I have a problem whene I want to access the current connected user from my service I have this error:

> An error occurred while loading the web debug toolbar (500: Internal Server Error).
>   Do you want to open the profiler?

And when I open the profiler I have this:

> FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function getUser() on a non-object in D:\Sites\Test\src\Test\BlogBundle\Service\VideoService.php line 110

Here is all the parts of my files:
services.yml

```
services:
    Test_site.video:
        class: Test\SiteBundle\Service\VideoService
        arguments: [%folder%, @service_container, @doctrine.orm.entity_manager, @security.context]
        tags:
            -  { name: twig.extension }
```

VideoService.php

```
protected $context;
public function __construct($folder, $container, \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $em, $context){
    $this->folder = $folder;
    $this->container = $container;
    $this->em = $em;
    $this->context = $context;
}
//Line 110 
$user = $this->context->getToken()->getUser();
```

And for the security.yml I think that the route is behind the firewall:

```
firewalls:  
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        pattern:        ^/
        provider:       main
```

since the route is localhost/Test/

Comment: You need to check if the security-context actually has a token before you try to get the user from it.

Comment: I did a var_dump, and yes he has a full token :/ the problem occure when the debug toolbar is loading !!

Comment: I understand that ... but the toolbar uses a sub-request where this ain't the case. So that's why you face the exception.

Comment: Did you get an answer for this